# Win7 WLAN internet access but not identifying network

Tags: windows-7

I have internet access but the icon in the taskbar seems wrong.

Here is a screenshot of the situation

[image]

I even get a red x sometimes.  Though still Internet access

[image]

Comment: update, i will put tihs in my q too  I viewed my network adaptors, looked at   tried this, couldn't see a route for hamachi doing route print..  http://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi/Hamachi-conflicts-with-internet-network-adapter-conflict/td-p/60088      tried this http://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi/CAN-T-disable-Hamachi-adapter-in-Windows-7-Reconnects/td-p/112791   shifted wireless network connection up and renamed hamachi and disabled it. Still same kind of problem. same icons

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have the latest driver for your network card

Check to see if Network Location Awareness is set to automatic:

1. Hold down the Window’s key and press r
2. Type services.msc and click OK
3. Right click on Network Location Awareness > click Properties
4. In the General tab check to see if the Startup type is set to Automatic

Your account may not have full permission over the Local Service process, in which case:

1. Click start > right click on Computer > click Manage
2. In the Computer Management console, click System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Groups
3. Now right click on Administrators > Add to Group > Add > Advanced > Find now > click Local Service and finally click Ok
4. Restart your computer

Or you could try resetting the taskbar notification area:
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/13102-notification-area-icons-reset.html

Comment: I haven't checked drivers yet.. could you elaborate on that.. checking drivers. I have a load of network adaptors including some from vmware and virtualbox.   Re "network location awareness" that's automatic and started. And, i've added "local service" to administrators.

Comment: I executed the bat file at the last link for resetting the taskbar, but it said "The Explorer process must be killed to reset the Notification Area Icons Cache.

Please SAVE ALL OPEN WORK before continuing

Press any key to continue . . .
"    So I am not sure I trust it since I have some files open.. and  killing explorer wouldn't affect it but the file gives that warning. Maybe the file's author is just ignorant, or maybe he's just patronising, but I am not yet willing to run it.  (what of the perhaps remote chance that what the bat file's author says is true/not rubbish)

Comment: To update your network driver (you may already have the latest one installed) you can use the information here:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/fix-network-adapter-problems#%23&1TC=windows-

Scroll down and follow the “Update the network adapter driver” section.

The link above also covers the answer given by JavaOnLunch if you wanted to uninstall the network driver and allow Windows to then find and install the correct one.

Comment: I ran the troubleshooter, but I can't see what network adaptor would be associated with where the taskbar popup shows unidentified network no network access. I chose the option to run it on all network adaptors and it found no  problems, so that didn't work. Also that link suggested that as a thing to try when you don't have a network connection.. I do have an internet connection. As for uninstalling - the link you mention had a link that talked about removing it from a slot, doesn't apply really 'cos I have a laptop i'm not opening. And anyhow i'm using a wireless  USB. adaptor

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a work computer awhile back, and remember [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/network-icon-show-red-x-even-though-wireless/2cf5b096-cd1d-4d57-ab43-fd0539a24787?page=1) being helpful. More specifically, the following steps:

"I had the same issue and this is how i solved it
services.msc set "WWAN AutoConfig" to automatic, and start the service.
in device manager uninstall ALL network adapters. Then right click and select "Scan Hardware For Changes" allow windows 7 to install the adapters. (No need to select remove driver)
This solved the problem for me."

I thought it was a driver issue and must have reinstalled the driver five times with no result, however, it doesn't hurt to double check and make sure you're using a correct and updated version of your driver for your network adapter.

If you like, run cmd as administrator and use the following command to manually reset the TCP/IP stacks, as well.

netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt

This will generate a log file (you can be more specific with the above directory path if you want) which may give more insight into the problem if it persists.

Comment: you mention uninstalling all network adaptors, some are vmware and virtualbox and i'm not keen on messing those up